# Unable to mock a method with generic parameters

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have a function with the following definition in a class, say Stack -

```
public <K, T> T nameOfFunction(final String string1, final K usebByFunction, final Class<T> returnType)
```

I have used the following Mockito call -

```
Mockito.when(instanceOfStack.nameOfFunction((String) any(), - , - ).thenThrow(CallFailedException.class))
```

I am able to mock the String parameter using (String) any(), but unable to mock the other two - K and Class. I need to mock this call to throw a CallFailedException.

Comment: You have anyString() which avoid the cast; as for the other, what did you try ? (because any(K.class), K.class should work).

Comment: It didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mockito.any() is not applicable for the type Class in your case. Should be fine if you specify Mockito.any(Class.class) in your condition.

```
public class TestClass
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public <K, T> T test(String s, K obj, final Class<T> clazz)
        {
            return null;    
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void test()
    {
        MyClass myClass = Mockito.mock(MyClass.class);

        Mockito.when(myClass.test(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(), Mockito.any(Class.class))).thenThrow(new IllegalArgumentException());

        myClass.test(null, null, null);
    }
}
```